# Cannot find module 'debug'

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I got this error today. Im using adonisjs and i cant find any "debug" referece. Am I forgeting something?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
Require stack:
- C:\ProjetosNode\buscanota_ck\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js
- C:\ProjetosNode\buscanota_ck\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\index.js
- C:\ProjetosNode\buscanota_ck\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProjetosNode\buscanota_ck\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\ProjetosNode\\buscanota_ck\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\ignitor\\src\\Ignitor\\index.js',
    'C:\\ProjetosNode\\buscanota_ck\\node_modules\\@adonisjs\\ignitor\\index.js',
    'C:\\ProjetosNode\\buscanota_ck\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

Problem solved
solution: reinstalled Node_modules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`. Possible some dependencies became corrupt.